# Is there some indicator for false positives on the Legendre symbol?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For example, $$\left({35 \over 13}\right) = 1$$ yet $x^2 - 35y^2 = 13$ has no solutions in integers. For a non-UFD like this, is there some way to take the Legendre symbol, add to it or multiply it by something else, like maybe something to the power of the class number to get the $-1$ meaning that $13$ is irreducible in this particular domain of algebraic integers? (I do know $13$ is not prime since $(-3 + \sqrt{35})(3 + \sqrt{35}) = 2 \times 13 = 26$).

Comment: In your specific case, there is no solution because $x^2\equiv 13\pmod 5$ has no solution. But that approach is not, in general, enough.

Answer (score 4):

At the very least, if $x^2-dy^2=n$ has a solution for some $d,n$ square-free, then if $p\mid d$ and $q\mid n$ are prime then $d$ is a square modulo $q$ and $n$ is a square modulo $p$. Your example fails this test, since $13$ is not a square modulo neither $5$ nor $7$.

But this is known to not be enough. Even the case $n=-1$ is very tricky ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation)), and has proved somewhat intractable over the years, except by computing the continued fraction for $\sqrt{d}$ explicitly.